# Computing tangent with x87 instructions FPTAN and FDIVR

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x87

I want to compute `tan(pi)` with X87 FPTAN and FDIVR:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

  double answer,angle=3.14;
  __asm__ ("FPTAN;"
       "FDIVR;"
       : "=t" (answer) : "0" (angle));
  printf ("angle = %g\n",angle);
  printf ("answer = %g\n",answer);

}
```

But I get a compilation error

```
error: unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix
      __asm__ ("FPTAN;"
               ^
<inline asm>:1:8: note: instantiated into assembly here
        FPTAN;FDIVR;
              ^
1 error generated.
```

How can I get ride of the error? It seems a size suffix is needed but I do not see how to construct the instruction.

For information, my "gcc -v" returns

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Exactly the same error message with lowercase

Comment: I'm not seeing this error.  What version of gcc are you using?  What compile switches?

Comment: Also, try using FPTANL.

Comment: Hmm.  How about "FPTAN;FDIVRP"?  It compiles in clang, but I'm not sure FDIVRP does exactly what you need?

Comment: @David  fptanl does not work. I wonder if there is alternative way to compute tangent?

Comment: Try `fdivrp;`. This handles the error on my clang (wheezy).

Comment: @rkhb & David FDIVRP seems working. Thanks so much. What does suffix P mean? I wanted to get a tangent function from double to double.

Comment: Docs for FDIVRP (and company): http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_92.html

Comment: Problem solved! Thans you all.